# Edit HTML table and capture changes as POST using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I just started off with javascript and html, so please correct me if I am doing it the wrong way. I was trying to edit an html form table.

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%block content%}
<html>
<body>
<h4> Search results</h4>
<p id="data"></p>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<form id="update" action="/update/" method="POST">
<script>
function onEdit(btn)
{
    var id=btn.id;
    if(btn.value=="Edit") {
            var input = document.getElementsByName("name"+id);
            for(i = 0;i < input.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById(input[i].id).removeAttribute("Readonly");
            } //End of for loop
            document.getElementById(id).value="Save";

            return false;
    }
    if(btn.value=="Save") {
        for(i = 0;i < input.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById(input[i].id).setAttribute("Readonly", "readonly");
            }
        document.getElementById(id).value="Edit";
        return false;
    }

} // End of Function onEdit()

{% autoescape off %}
var data = {{ search|safe }}; //This will be the json value returned by django view
{% endautoescape %}
text = ''
var out = "<table style=\"width:50%\">";
out +=    "<tr>";
out +=    "<th>Domain</th>";
out +=    "<th>Points to</th>";
out +=    "<th>Type</th>";
out +=    "<th>TTL</th>";
out +=  "</tr>";
var i 
var id = 0;
for ( var i = 0; i < data.records.length; i++) {
id = id + 1;
out += "<tr><td>" +
"<input readonly='readonly' name='name" + id + "' id='" + data.records[i].domain + "' value='" + data.records[i].domain + "'type='text'/>" +
"</td><td>" +
"<input readonly='readonly' name='name" + id + "' id='" + data.records[i].record_points_to + "' value='" + data.records[i].record_points_to +"'type='text'/>" +
"</td><td>" +
data.records[i].record +
"</td><td>" +
"<input readonly='readonly' name='name" + id + "' id='" + data.records[i].ttl + "' value='" + data.records[i].ttl + "'type='text'/>" +
"</td><td>" +
"<input id='" + id + "' value='Edit' onclick='return onEdit(this)' type='button'/>" +
"</td></tr>";
}
out += "</table>"

total = data.meta.total_records
page = data.meta.page
records_returned = data.records.length
records_shown = ((data.meta.page - 1) * 30) + data.records.length

out += records_shown + " returned of " + total
page = data.meta.page + 1
link = window.location.href
if (records_shown == total){
out += " End "
}
else{
url ="<a href='" + updateQueryStringParameter(link, "page", page) + "'> Next"

out += url
}
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}


document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = out
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have the page displayed as expected.

What I am trying to achieve is to make these html tables editable, which is also working half way. When I click the Edit button, the table link turns editable, and I can change the value, and the Edit button changes to Save. 
But when I click on "Save" button, firebug error shows

`TypeError: input is undefined`

`for(i = 0;i < input.length; i++) {`

`----------↑`
(Yes, arrow points to var i)

I want to capture the changes when I click on Save, and whatever changes in that page should be captured via POST method once clicked on the submit button below. Submit is redirected to `action="/update/"`. Please let me know what should I do.

Comment: You are assigning the variable _input_ in the "Edit", but not in the "Save". Could that be the issue?

Comment: I need caffeine. Yes, I misplaced it by an `if` block. Human error. I can take it from here. Please update this in the answer section, and I will accept it. Thank you Alvaro.

Comment: Glad it worked, and no need to set it as an answer as it is a really specific thing. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

to avoid such problems please define all variables at the beginning of their scope (the scope is a function in case of Javascript)